# How do you extract just date from datetime in T-Sql?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am running a select against a datetime column in SQL Server 2005. I can select only the date from this datetime column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best way is:

```
   SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @ADate), 0)
```

This is because internally, SQL Server stores all dates as two integers, of which the first one is the ****number of days*** since 1 Jan 1900. (the second one is the time portion, stored as the number of seconds since Midnight.  (seconds for `SmallDateTime`s, or milleseconds for `DateTime`s)
Using the above expression is better because it avoids all conversions, directly reading and accessing that first integer in a dates internal representation without having to perform any processing...  the two zeroes in the above expression (which represent 1 Jan 1900), are also directly utilized w/o processing or conversion, because they match the SQL server internal representation of the date 1 jan 1900 exactly as presented (as an integer)..

*NOTE.  Actually, the number of date boundaries (midnights) you have to cross to get from the one date to the other.

Comment: I figured it out before looking at the response, but this is the way I went, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, by using the convert function.  For example:

```
select getdate(), convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
----------------------- ----------
2010-05-21 13:43:23.117 2010-05-21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions:

1. `day(date)`
2. `month(date)`
3. `year(date)`

Comment: Is there any similar functions for time part as well? Like hour(date), minute(date). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also the Datepart() function might be of some use:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CONVERT (date, GETUTCDATE())
CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
CONVERT (date, '2022-18-01')
```

I don't know why the others recommend it with varchar(x) tbh.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dToday DATETIME
SET @dToday = CONVERT(nvarchar(20), GETDATE(), 101)
SELECT @dToday AS Today
```

This returns today's date at 12:00am : '2010-05-21 00:00:00.000'
Then you can use the @dToday variable in a query as needed