# Want to print declared date and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to get declared `Month` and `date` by the below query, but I am getting something as

`Jul 21 1905 12:00AM`

I want it as

`Dec 31 2015`

below is my query

```
declare @actualMonth int 
  declare @actualYear int
set  @actualYear = 2015
set @actualMonth = 12
 DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = CAST(@actualYear +'-' + @actualMonth AS datetime) 
 print  @DATE
```

what is wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you as expected output,

```
DECLARE @actualMonth INT 
DECLARE @actualYear INT
SET @actualYear = 2015
SET @actualMonth = 12
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME;
SET @DATE = CAST(
        CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR)+'-'+'31' 
        AS DATETIME
    );

PRINT Convert(varchar(11),@DATE,109)
```

Try this,

```
SET @DATE = CAST(
        CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR)+'-'+ Cast(Day(DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(month,@actualMonth,DATEADD(year,@actualYear-1900,0)))) AS VARCHAR)
        AS DATETIME
    );
```

Or this one,

```
SET @DATE = CAST(
        CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR)+'-'+'01' 
        AS DATETIME
    );

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, 1, @DATE)), 109)
```

Comment: one more thing, **will it give me last day for, if year and month added dynamically** ??

Comment: yeah for that you need to use something like `DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR),DATEADD(year,CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR)-1900,0)))`  instead of `31`

Comment: can you update sir, so that I can mark it as answer. because with your current query, I am getting error as `The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.` for the month of FEB

Comment: I have update but don't know weather `Day` function is supporting it in `SQL server 2005` or not

Comment: Your second `SET=date` is giving first day of the month, but first `SET` is working fine for me.. Thanks a  lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are   actualMonth  and  actualYear  and converting as datetime it wil give other result 
Try like this

```
declare @actualMonth int 
declare @actualYear int
set  @actualYear = 2015
set @actualMonth = 12
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(YY,1,CAST(@actualYear   AS varchar(20)) ))

select SUBSTRING(convert (varchar,@DATE),0,CHARINDEX(':',convert (varchar,@DATE))-2)
print  @DATE
```

Comment: you have set `@actualYear` as `2016` why ??

Comment: initially your question is like 2016 now it modified @coder anyway i will edit

Comment: Try for year=2015 month=11

Answer (score 1):

You should convert those month and year to varchar and then convert the final result to datetime. It should be

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME;

SET @DATE = CAST(CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR) + '-' + '31' AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: yes its working perfectly, i dont want time part.. only `year, month and day`

Comment: Then cast it to a date rather and declare your variable of sametype.

Comment: i am using `2005` sql and it doesn't works for `date`

Comment: Right! in that case you can use `DATEADD()` function or datetime functions to get date/month/year. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885400/how-do-you-extract-just-date-from-datetime-in-t-sql

Comment: one more thing, **will it give me last day for, if year and month added dynamically** ??

Answer (score 1):

It is no so trivial as seems. You should handle correct last days for each month.

```
DECLARE @actualMonth int 
DECLARE @actualYear int
SET @actualYear = 2016
SET @actualMonth = 2
DECLARE @tmpDate DATETIME

SET @tmpDate = CAST(CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR), 2) + '01' AS DATETIME);
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 1, @tmpDate)), 100)
```

**Update**

Ok, I'll try to explain problem more deeper.

What is different between extended (used by @rajeshpanchal) and basic (used by me) formats of `ISO 8601`?

In fact the SQL Server treats date(datetime) specified in basic and extended formats differently regarding `DATEFORMAT` setting.

Look at this code:

```
Declare @str1 varchar(8) = '20160121'
Declare @str2 varchar(10) = '2016-01-21'

Declare @dt1 datetime
Declare @dt2 datetime
--set dateformat ydm ---- 1
set dateformat ymd   -----2
set @dt1 = @str1
set @dt2 = @str2
select @dt1
select @dt2
```

This code will work correctly. But when you uncomment first and comment second `set dateformat` (dateformat set to `ydm`) the extended format will fail when basic format will work correctly.

Comment: not working when I add Year and Month as `2016` and `2` respectively

Comment: Yup, it's working too. I prefered `rajeshpanchal` answer more accurate though. Upvoted +1 for trying. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @coder, look at the more deeper explanation of problem.